# Running chrome as a different domain user in Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ui-automation

The application I am testing behaves differently for different users based on the Active Directory roles assigned to them. So I used to launch applications as a different user in windows by holding down `shift` key and right clicking the application icon/ shortcut and choose 'Run As a Different User' option, then I'll be prompted to enter user name and password for the different user.

Now I am on a Mac and I am trying to run chrome browser as a different network user. I am not able to find how to do it yet.

Writing this here to check if this is possible in Mac for Chrome.

Has any one achieved this before ? If yes, can you please tell me how I can achieve this too ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to achieve what I want

I just did `kinit <username>` from the terminal and entered the password when prompted and just refreshed the page in chrome to find that I am viewing the page as the `username` that I did `kinit` with.

Just thought I'll leave this response here.